# A regular expression which excludes comments lines starting with "//" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, comments, line

I need to find all lines with string "new qx.ui.form.Button" WHICH EXCLUDE lines starting with comments "//".

Example

```
line 1:"      //btn = new qx.ui.form.Button(plugin.menuName, plugin.menuIcon).set({"
line 2:"      btn = new qx.ui.form.Button(plugin.menuName, plugin.menuIcon).set({"
```

Pattern should catch only "line 2"!
Be aware about leading spaces.

Finally I have to **FIND** and **REPLACE** "new qx.ui.form.Button" in all **UNCOMMENTED** code lines with "this.__getButton".

I tried.

```
/new.*Button/g
/[^\/]new.*Button/g
```

and many others without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript this is a bit icky:

```
^\s*(?=\S)(?!//)
```

excludes a comment at the start of a line. So far, so standard. But you cannot look backwards for this pattern because JS doesn't support arbitrary-length lookbehind, so you have to match and replace more than needed:

```
^(\s*)(?=\S)(?!//)(.*)(new qx\.ui\.form\.Button)
```

Replace that by

```
$1$2this.__getButton
```

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS Home:\> $line1 -replace '^(\s*)(?=\S)(?!//)(.*)(new qx\.ui\.form\.Button)','$1$2this.__getButton'
      //btn = new qx.ui.form.Button(plugin.menuName, plugin.menuIcon).set({
PS Home:\> $line2 -replace '^(\s*)(?=\S)(?!//)(.*)(new qx\.ui\.form\.Button)','$1$2this.__getButton'
      btn = this.__getButton(plugin.menuName, plugin.menuIcon).set({
```

That being said, why do you care about what's in the commented lines anyway? It's not as if they had any effect on the program.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, if only JavaScript had lookbehinds... Then all you'd need is
`/(?<!\/\/.*)new\s+qx\.ui\.form\.Button/g`... Ah well.

This'll work just fine too:

```
.replace(/(.*)new\s(qx\.ui\.form\.Button)/g,function(_,m) {
    // note that the second set of parentheses aren't needed
    // they are there for readability, especially with the \s there.
    if( m.indexOf("//") > -1) {
        // line is commented, return as-is
        // note that this allows comments in an arbitrary position
        // to only allow comments at the start of the line (with optional spaces)
        // use if(m.match(/^\s*\/\//))
        return _;
    }
    else {
        // uncommented! Perform replacement
        return m+"this.__getButton";
    }
});
```

Comment: Notepad++ supports lookbehinds, so just use that first regex I gave and replace matches with `this.__getButton`

Answer (score 0):

Grep uses Regular Expressions, this will exclude all white space (if any) plus two // at the beginning of any line.
    grep -v "^\s*//"